# How to retrieving key and value from firebase and store them in two separate variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am create login activity it's consist two Edit-text username and password
And I want to check login username and password from firebase database real-time 
I am saved this inside object name 'user' like this

```
{
  "users" : {
    "admin" : "a",
    "table1" : "t1",
    "table2" : "t2",
    "table3" : "t3",
    "table4" : "t4",
    "table5" : "t5",
    "table6" : "t6",
    "table7" : "t7",
    "table8" : "t8",
    "table9" : "t9",
    "table10" : "t10",
    }
}
```

this code kotlin

```
    private lateinit var database:FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

    // initlize 
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    reference = database.getReference()

    inner class ReadData : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext , p0.message.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            for(data in p0.children){

               Log.i("LIST IN FIREBASE",data.toString())

            }
        }
    }
}

fun login(view: View) {
    var readData = ReadData()
    reference.addValueEventListener(readData)
}
```

I can access to key('admin','table1',...etc),
but I cannot access to value ('a','t1',...etc) 
how to do check login like this structure  ?

Don't care about syntax kotlin or java
write syntax code as you like

Comment: Share your code snippets to.

Answer (score 0):

First reach to child mode `users` and then add event listener.

```
reference.child("users").addValueEventListener(readData)
```

And then try to parse `key` and `value` inside `onDataChange`

```
for(data in p0.children) { 

    val key = data.key
    val value = data.getValue(String::class.java)

    Log.i("LIST IN FIREBASE",data.toString())
}
```